# Renewing - Azure App Service SSL Certificate

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I have an AppService where the SSL Certificate is getting expired. I have the renewed certificate. Is there a way to upload this through powershell without causing outage?

Also, I intend to automate the entire process for certificate renewal and changing in AppService is this be done through Keyvault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload your renewed certificate and bind it to your app service, you could use this powershell command [`New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding?view=azurermps-6.6.0).

For Auto Renew [App Service Certificate](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/internals-of-app-service-certificate/), you could check it in your **App Service Certificate** -> **Auto Renew Settings** -> **Auto Renew App Service Certificate**, if Auto Renew is on then it will be renewed automatically before it expires, the linked App Service Apps will be moved to the new certificate.